# Tensorflow: how to share ops in the graph?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

It's about creating a graph that is as simple as possible and as such later on being able to inspect it. The relevant part of the code is this and I think this is a typical chunk of code for creating a generative adversarial training (next is a simplified network which doesn't work in practice):

```
def generator(x):
    w_init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
    b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.)
    l1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 256, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='layer_1')
    l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 512, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='layer_2')
    o = tf.layers.dense(l2, 784, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.tanh, name='layer_out')
    return o

def discriminator(x, reuse=False):
    w_init = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)
    b_init = tf.constant_initializer(0.)
    x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 784])
    l1 = tf.layers.dense(x, 1024, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='layer_1')
    l2 = tf.layers.dense(l1, 512, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='layer_2')
    o = tf.layers.dense(l2, 1, kernel_initializer=w_init, bias_initializer=b_init, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid, name='layer_out')
    return o

with tf.variable_scope('input_variables'):
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 28, 28, 1), name='real_images')
    z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, noise_size), name='noise_vector')

with tf.variable_scope('generator'):
    G_z = generator(z)

with tf.variable_scope('discriminator', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
    D_real = discriminator(x)
    D_fake = discriminator(G_z, reuse=True)
```

And the Tensorflow graph of my entire code looks like this:
[image]

Now I tried everything with 'tf.name_scope' and 'tf.variable_scope' but there is one thing that I cannot do and that is merging the ops. Tensorflow automatically creates the same operations again for the network. This means, for example in this setup and graph, it will always create 'layer_1' and layer_1_2'. I think I understand what it is all doing. But what I don't understand is why it is not possible to scope this into one layer, with only one block of ops and one block where the variables are generated. As such, in the graph there would only be one network inside 'discriminator' and the choice is just made at the input. I think basically this comes down to why it is not possible for making a graph where, after reshaping, the network looks at it as a larger batch because now the ops are identical?

Answer (score 1):

You never share ops in tensorflow. Given that a op has a fixed input(during a run), there's no point in running the same op again since it will give you the same output.

However it makes sense to share weights/variables. Say you have a dense fully connected layer that you apply to two different tensors (fake data and real one in your case). Note that the inputs are different, so these will be different ops. Use `tf.variable_scope(..., reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE)` to reuse the variables.

If you really want to have a single op in your graph, an option is to concat the inputs into something that would look like a batch twice the size of your current batch and run the op on the concatenated tensor. This way you make sure that you are applying the same operations to both inputs, and maybe you get some small speed boost (similar to what you would get from larger batch).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Concatenating them is what I was doing now to avoid having this over-complex graph. The point is actually why tensorflow does not know that after the reshape ops, apart from the batch size, the network inputs have the same dimensions and should be undergoing exactly the same calculations because of the variable sharing. Therefor I don't understand why the computational graph is not automatically made simpler? Has it something to do with synchronised in time when computed?

Comment: I know a better way to express my thoughts :) An Op can be used as a fixed operation but the input/output values can be changed, right? So, why can I not make this on a higher level? Thus that the network becomes the Op? Or if possible, how will I have to do that?

Comment: @JeroenBertels I think you got it. Why is this way, I'm not fully sure. Probably because someone thought it would be simpler.